# System identification in Matlab Simulink

Tags: matlab, system-identification

I am using a pulse sensor the input data to matlab is step function and the output of my system is the pulse so when I were using system identification toolbox i inserted the input and output of the system then I pressed import, it said you have more input channels than data points and it wants to transpose the input channel so what should I do what does this mean please help me.
I have 1*2897 double for pulse data (output) and 1*2897points for step data (input).

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry if you have already tried this, but transposing the input channel might simply require you to transpose the input data matrix.

As in, if your input channel is Inp, a (1xN) array, you simply need to do

```
Inp = Inp';
```

which would make it an (Nx1) array.

Reference: https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/transpose.html